# Error in using WHERE for search function in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I made a controller to search something ,
but the result was weird:

My code:

```
  def create
    @word = searching_params[:word]
    @searching = current_user.searchings.build(word: @word)
    flash[:notice] = "New searching is performed!" if @searching.save
    @users = User.where("firstname LIKE ? OR lastname LIKE ?", "%#{@word}%", "%#{@word}%")
    @posts = Post.where("body LIKE ?", "%#{@word}%")
    render :index
  end
```

So, when i searched for a name: Mose Collins,

o, se, ose could get the result,

but m, c, co and others would give me nothing.

Comment: replace `LIKE` with `ILIKE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` performs a case sensitive match. If you want to perform a case insensitive match in a somewhat polyglot fashion you can use the LOWER() SQL function:

```
@users = User.where("LOWER(firstname) LIKE ? OR LOWER(lastname) LIKE ?", "%#{@word.downcase}%", "%#{@word.downcase}%")
```

Postgres has a `ILIKE` function which is case insensitive:

```
@users = User.where("firstname ILIKE ? OR lastname ILIKE ?", "%#{@word.downcase}%", "%#{@word.downcase}%")
```

You can also use Arel to construct it instead of a SQL string:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorite_jobs

  def self.search(term)
    where(
      arel_table[:firstname].matches("#{name}").or(
        arel_table[:lastname].matches("#{name}")
      )
    )
  end
end
```

This approach is more portable and espcially shines if you want to built the query programatically.